# how to remove Polyline API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the following code to create a polyline on google maps where pts in a list of points.

```
  walkroute = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: pts,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.4,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        geodesic: true'
      });
   walkroute.setMap(map);
```

I am using the following code to then try and remove the polyline but it does not appear to remove the polyline. can someone please give me the correct way to check if a polyline exists on the map and if so how to remove it.

```
function clearploylines();
if (walkroute === "undefined"){
  if (walkroute.getMap === null) {
    walkroute.setMap(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: You set the map only to null if it is already null. Shouldn't it be if (walkroute.getMap != null) ?

Comment: ... and also `if (walkroute != "undefined")` ?

Answer (score 0):

I created an **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUkCs/12/)** for you which shows how to hide or show same polyline.

It basically boils down to rows of:

```
function removePolyline() {

    // polyline exists, remove
    if(typeof polyline !== 'undefined') {
        polyline.setMap(null);
    }

}
```

Within your case, *polyline* variable is same as *walkroute*, but you will get the point when you open the js fiddle code.